# Freemarker get element from list

Tags: freemarker, smooks

I am doing teplate which i will use in Smooks conversion. I need to get f.e. 2nd element of the list in freemarker but i have no idea how to do it. There is fragment of my code in freemarker template.

```
<#list partnerList as PARTNER>
    ${PARTNER.partnrid}
    ${PARTNER.name}
</#list>
```

and there is java class:

```
public class Partner {
    private String PARTNRID;
    private String NAME;

  public String getPartnrid() {
  return PARTNRID;
 }
 public void setPARTNRID(String PARTNRID) {
  this.PARTNRID = PARTNRID;
 }
 public String getName() {
  return NAME;
 }
 public void setNAME(String NAME) {
  this.NAME = NAME;
 }
}
```

As i said before i need ONLY 2nd element. I want to avoid printing the rest items.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the second element of the list like this:

```
${partnerList[1].name}
```

See the freemarker documentation [here](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_var_sequence).

Answer (score 1):

You can also obtain the name by writing as shown below

```
<#list partnerList as PARTNER>
<#if PARTNER.partnrid??>
 <partnrid>${PARTNER.partnrid}</partnrid>
</#if>
<name>${PARTNER.name}</name>
</#list>
```